# Cannot run from Jar File but runs in IDE the curl command , need to know why?

Tags: java, curl

I created on NetBeans an application that gets via Curl command a JSON String. Runs all good within the IDE and when I build the jar works perfectly. I installed the application on another PC. It runs perfect from the IDE but not from the jar. I tried several solutions but nothing works. Any ideas?

I've **tried** to download to system32 the curl.exe from some page,
I've **also tried** installed some windows libraries like the c++  package.

I've also read that its the path. What path, how I set it. Am not sure.

```
ProcessBuilder p=new ProcessBuilder("curl","--show-error", "--request","GET","--header","Accept: application/json", "--user",this.getAccessKey() + ":" +this.getSecretKey(), url);

Process pr = p.start();
result = IOUtils.toString(pr.getInputStream());
```

Cannot run program **"curl"**

Comment: I think the problem comes from the working directory. Can You post the command line how do You run it using JAR? is it just `java -jar jarname.jar`?

Comment: @echo off          

java -jar "C:\Academic_Check_Grades 2.1.0\dist\Academic_Check_Grades_2.1.0.jar"
pause

Comment: Is there PATH java variable in your system?

Comment: in the System Variables nothing is set for Java

Comment: 3 things to try: 1st: Is the `curl` "visible" from a command line (is it somewhere where PATH points to)? 2nd: try to run Your jar from Your `c:\Acad.../dist` directory. 3rd: just for test: use a full path to `curl` in `new ProcessBuilder("c:\\full\\path\\curl"....);`

Comment: Thanks bro. You recommendations really helped and found a solution. I moved the curl.exe and curl-ca-bundle.crt files into the dist folder where the jar is located and now executes as it supposed too. Cheers